# How to count max date row if current status column is 0 or 2?

Tags: postgresql

### Example Data and Table

```
Currentstatus   Datetime                  Open_reopen_status  Parent_id
-------------   -----------------------   ------------------  ---------
5                                         0                   214
5                                         1                   214
0               2017-09-25 18:23:07.181   0                   214
5               2017-10-18 00:00:00       0                   214
5                                         0                   214
5                                         1                   214
0               2017-09-25 18:23:07.181   0                   214
5               2017-10-18 00:00:00       0                   214
5               2017-09-25 00:00:00       0                   226
5               2017-09-25 00:00:00       1                   226
0               2018-10-04 18:33:15.762   0                   226
5               2018-10-06 00:00:00       0                   226
5               2017-09-25 00:00:00       1                   226
0               2018-10-08 18:33:15.762   0                   226
5               2019-03-07 08:55:35.772   0                   126900
5               2019-03-27 15:51:28.63    1                   126900
0               2019-03-27 15:51:28.63    0                   126900
```

### Question

I need a count of those rows whose date is maximum and `currentstatus=0` along with particular id value.

E.g., in the above table the count would be 2, because the `parent_id` **226** and **126900** have a `currentstatus=0` and the max date `2018-10-08` and `2019-03-27`.

Comment: Unclear. Why you decide 126900  matches? MaxDate for it is `2019-03-27 15:51:28.63`, and there exists a record with this datetime value and `status=5`.

Comment: because last record having currentstatus 0

Comment: "Last" status of this record is positional. But there is NO positional records ordering in a table. So when we query the same data next time these two records may swap freely. ORDER BY is the only reason for ordering. What ordering we must use to obtain this record as last? Is `ORDER BY Datetime DESC, Currentstatus DESC` safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understand your question is, for each `Parent_id` you want to determine the maximum `Datetime` and then find the rows that have both the maximum `Datetime` and the `Currentstatus` of 0. And finally you want to count the resulting rows.

First of all, you can get the maximum `Datetime` values using a window aggregate function `MAX() OVER ()`:

```
SELECT
  Currentstatus,
  Datetime,
  Open_reopen_status,
  Parent_id,
  MAX(Datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY Parent_id) AS MaxDatetime
FROM
  YourTable
;
```

That will give you a result set like this:

```
Currentstatus  Datetime                 Open_reopen_status  Parent_id  MaxDatetime
-------------  -----------------------  ------------------  ---------  -----------------------
5                                       0                   214        2017-10-18 00:00:00
5                                       1                   214        2017-10-18 00:00:00
0              2017-09-25 18:23:07.181  0                   214        2017-10-18 00:00:00
5              2017-10-18 00:00:00      0                   214        2017-10-18 00:00:00
5                                       0                   214        2017-10-18 00:00:00
5                                       1                   214        2017-10-18 00:00:00
0              2017-09-25 18:23:07.181  0                   214        2017-10-18 00:00:00
5              2017-10-18 00:00:00      0                   214        2017-10-18 00:00:00
5              2017-09-25 00:00:00      0                   226        2018-10-08 18:33:15.762
5              2017-09-25 00:00:00      1                   226        2018-10-08 18:33:15.762
0              2018-10-04 18:33:15.762  0                   226        2018-10-08 18:33:15.762
5              2018-10-06 00:00:00      0                   226        2018-10-08 18:33:15.762
5              2017-09-25 00:00:00      1                   226        2018-10-08 18:33:15.762
0              2018-10-08 18:33:15.762  0                   226        2018-10-08 18:33:15.762
5              2019-03-07 08:55:35.772  0                   126900     2019-03-27 15:51:28.63
5              2019-03-27 15:51:28.63   1                   126900     2019-03-27 15:51:28.63
0              2019-03-27 15:51:28.63   0                   126900     2019-03-27 15:51:28.63
```

Use the query as a derived table and apply this filter to it:

```
WHERE Datetime = MaxDatetime
  AND Currentstatus = 0
```

which for your example will match these two rows:

```
Currentstatus  Datetime                 Open_reopen_status  Parent_id  MaxDatetime
-------------  -----------------------  ------------------  ---------  -----------------------
0              2018-10-08 18:33:15.762  0                   226        2018-10-08 18:33:15.762
0              2019-03-27 15:51:28.63   0                   126900     2019-03-27 15:51:28.63
```

And now it only remains for you to put `COUNT(*)` in the main `SELECT`. This is the full query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS CountResult
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Currentstatus,
      Datetime,
      Open_reopen_status,
      Parent_id,
      MAX(Datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY Parent_id) AS MaxDatetime
    FROM
      YourTable
  ) AS derived
WHERE Datetime = MaxDatetime
  AND Currentstatus = 0
;
```

Note that if there can be two or more matching rows per `Parent_id` and you want to count only the different `Parent_id` values, you need to express that in your query. The easiest way would be to replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT Parent_id)`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT Parent_id) AS CountResult
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Currentstatus,
      Datetime,
      Open_reopen_status,
      Parent_id,
      MAX(Datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY Parent_id) AS MaxDatetime
    FROM
      YourTable
  ) AS derived
WHERE Datetime = MaxDatetime
  AND Currentstatus = 0
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT DISTINCT Parent_id, 
                              FIRST_VALUE(Currentstatus) 
                                  OVER (PARTITION BY Parent_id 
                                        ORDER BY Datetime DESC NULLS LAST, 
                                                 Currentstatus ASC ) fv
              FROM datatable )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte 
WHERE fv = 0;
```